# How to scroll UITableView to the previous contentOffset after inserting items on the top

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

```
//Old table view height                
let oldHeight: CGFloat = self.tableView.contentSize.height

// Update table with indexpath array
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
self.tableView.insertRows(at: (indexPath as NSArray) as! [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

//Layout table view if needed
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

//New content offset
let newHeight: CGFloat = self.tableView.contentSize.height

//Set content offset
let adjustablePoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: newHeight - oldHeight)

//Set
self.tableView.setContentOffset(adjustablePoint, animated: false)
```

Above solution doesn't worked for me

Comment: You use both `self.tableView` and `self.chatTableView` in your code. Is that intentional, or maybe the source of your problem?

Comment: @Glorfindel I missed it while chaging naming convention while posting question, thanks for apprising, question has been edited now.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish. `UITableView` should keep the original content offset while inserting new rows **by default**. Also, why would you need to disable animations globally and instruct `insertRows` not to be animated at the same time?

Comment: Did you check if your height "new" and "old" has different sizes ? Also what is not working exactly in your solution ? does it scroll anywhere ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one important value in your calculations - current "y" offset after reloading. You are setting offset to be just a difference between new height and old height - which probably will scroll somewhere to the top.

Solution will be to replace this:

`let adjustablePoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: newHeight - oldHeight`)

with this:

```
let adjustablePoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentOffset.y + newHeight - oldHeight)
```

The idea is to move the table by the difference of heights relatively to the new position - so it should all happen after table view is reloaded and it's repositioned to it's automatic contentOffset calculated by UIKit.

I think that those lines are not required for you to achieve what you wanted:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
...
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
...
self.chatTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Try removing them after you confirm my calculation fix is working

Comment: unable to maintain same offSet .... and 'self.tableView.contentOffset.y' always return  0 have not impact on ajustablePoint...

Answer (score 0):

While `UITableView` is a subview of `UIScrollView`, there's a better way to scroll programmatically within table views. You can use the [`scrollToRow`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow) function; the 'last' index path can be found with [`numberOfSections`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614924-numberofsections) and [`numberOfRows`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614952-numberofrows).

Comment: I think he didn't really ask for last index path - more like previous content offset